# How to measure the performance of Mask RCNN model. Given that there are two tasks , one object detection and another image segmentation

Tags: neural-networks, model-evaluation, accuracy, object-detection, image-segmentation

Mask RCNN is an instance image segmentation technique. It is based on Faster RCNN for object detection and an additional mask operation is performed by another CNN.